# Disable window and transition settings

Tags: android, settings, android-contentresolver

So what I need to do is toggle window and/or transition animations on and off in code, to have the same effect of going Settings > Display > Animations > Disable all animations.

The way I am familiar with changing device settings is by using a ContentResolver within the Settings.System.putInt() method as follows:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, 0);
```

As described in the documentation 'Setting to 0 will disable all .... animations' for both settings. When reading the setting before and after using the putInt() method, using this:

```
Settings.System.getString(cr, Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE);
```

I can see that the setting is being changed. However when then doing something to begin a window or transition animation it is obvious to see that the setting hasn't made any difference and the transition still occurs.

I would also like to say that when I change the setting from within the Settings screen, I can see that the setting has been changed when I rerun my application. So it seems this is the correct setting and that my application isn't changing it correctly.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? Am struggling with the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Check you are setting the correct scales.

```
Settings.System.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE
```

Will change the Activity transitions.

Where as:

```
Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE
```

Will effect the Window animations such as Dialogs opening.

(Added API16) This will enable/disable View specific animations.

```
Settings.System.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE
```

Also I'm pretty sure these are `floats` as these can be 0.5x animation settings meaning half speed. I have never tried these from an App before.

But two things come to mind:

- The `ContentProvider` is asynchronous, and you will need to listen to the Setting to finished being set
- Also that these will probably not work until you create/finish and activity. meaning changing them mid activity might not effect the current `Activity`, but I will have to test that theory.