# How can I turn on animation programatically?

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I turn on animation programatically? I am using `overridePendingTransition();`. It doesn't work unless I turn on animation myself. Can anybody tell me how to turn on animations programatically which are inside display/Animation setting? I am using overridePendingTransition(); to open new activity .

here are my xml

grow_fadein_center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="0.6" android:toXScale="1.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6" android:toYScale="1.0"
           android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
    <alpha android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_interpolator"
            android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

shrink_fadeout_center :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.5"
           android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.5"
           android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
    <alpha android:interpolator="@anim/accelerate_interpolator"
            android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

and here is the code i am using to open intent

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, 0);

                Intent intent=new Intent(context,Second.class);


                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_fade_in_center, R.anim.shrink_fade_out_center);
                finish();

//testing on textview worked without turning system animation on.
                Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.grow_fade_in_center);
                txt.startAnimation(animation);




            }
        });
```

This works only when animations are turned on. and i am doing so by settings->display->animation

I found

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, 0);
```

to turn on or off animation by setting integer! but it didn't work for me!
what i need is how can i turned on/off animation programatically which are in system setting?

Comment: To do what? `overridePendingTransition()` is for Activity transitions.. what are you trying to do?!?

Comment: make your question more specific and provide your code....

Comment: @MBMJ & i added my code. sorry i was not clear before!

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins i added code here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to initiate the Animation pragmatically like that.

You just need to call `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_fade_in_center, R.anim.shrink_fade_out_center);` in the correct place.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(HomeActivity.class);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    finish();
}
```

Also doing:

```
Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, 0);
```

Will disabled window animations!

Comment: Well tried but doesnt work! i am using Htc explorer with gingerbread 2.3.5.

Comment: It works only when i turned it on manually! Even i face same problem on Lg optimus L7 with android ICS 4.0.3. On LG. here even i need to turned it on!

Comment: Well i am trying it either a way. if it has been enabled(which i did manually) then i tried to disable it. But neither it was disabling nor even enabling by code!. Actually i dont wanna change users setting. As soon as i closed app i will turned window animation to off. To enable and disable animation i took refrence of this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936946/disable-window-and-transition-settings] even he has the same requirement that i want. If you can solve it. We both will have solution. Thanks in advance